# Detect when two rectangles touch horizontally or vertically

Tags: ruby, collision-detection, collision, ruby2d

I have these two methods to determine collisions on the x-axis and y-axis:

```rb
def horizontal_overlap(char, object)
    char.x + char.width > object.x &&
    char.x < object.x + object.width  #Endl
end

def vertical_overlap(char, object)
    object.y + object.height > char.y &&
    object.y < char.y + char.height  #Endl
end
```

In my code, there is one moving rectangle and several other (fixed) rectangles. I want to detect if the moving rectangle *touches* one of the other rectangles. In addition, I want to determine if it touches it horizontally or vertically.

How do I approach this?

Comment: _"they don't work properly"_ – that's quite vague. What doesn't work in particular? Can you give an example for char and object pairs that don't work?

Comment: the vertical_overlap and horizontal_overlap functions don't work independently

Comment: Yes, you said so. Please provide an example of `char` and `object` so I can see what you mean by that.

Comment: An Example: ```@pl = Rectangle.new(x:400,y:300,width:50,height:50,color:'blue'), @char = Rectangle.new(x:500,y:300,width:50,height:50,color:'blue')```

Comment: Another Example:```horizontal_overlap(@pl,@char)``` or `vertical_overlap(@pl,@char)`

Comment: Returns either true of false depending on whether collision is detected **BUT** They don't work properly

Comment: Seems to work just fine:`horizontal_overlap(@pl,@char)` returns `false` because they don't overlay horizontally – `@pl` is left from `@char`. On the other hand, `vertical_overlap(@pl,@char)` returns `true` because they do overlap vertically – `@pl` and `@char` have the very same y-coordinate. Maybe you have a different understanding of "overlap". Please clarify what you mean by _"don't work properly"_. What do you expect? (and why)

Comment: Also ***@pl*** stands for player, Anyways.... The *horizontal_overlap* function returns **true** when ***@pl*** is to the right or the left of ***@char*** no matter how far ***@pl*** is from ***@char*** and the *vertical_overlap* function returns true when ***@pl*** is over of under ***@char*** no mater how far ***@pl*** is over or under from ***@char***. (Sorry for taking long to reply it's 'cuz I had to sweep the floor)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247706/discussion-between-stefan-and-issuseless).

Comment: 'Kay...........

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `#contains?(x, y) ⇒ Boolean` function.

Here the documentation
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby2d/Ruby2D/Rectangle